# Attribute error: module 'django.forms.forms has no attribute 'ModelForm'

Tags: python

```
from django.forms import forms
from .models import StudentModel


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
      'class': 'form-control',
       'placeholder' : 'Enter Name Here '
    }))

    age = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Age '
    }))

    address = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Address '
    }))

    email = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter  Email Here '
    }))

    pin = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter Pin Here '
    }))

    mob = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Enter Mobile Number Here '
    }))

    class Meta():
        model = StudentModel
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'address', 'email', 'pin', 'mob']
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

When I got the "AttributeError: module 'django.forms.forms' has no attribute 'ModelForm' ",  I checked my django modules and changed the field below.
When I first checked my module it was like this:

```
from django.forms import forms
    
#then I change as below field:
    
from django import forms
```

=> forms.ModelForm problem solved

Answer (score 2):

It should be `from django.forms import ModelForm` then you can use `class StudentForm(ModelForm):` or `from django import forms`.

Comment: okay @ujwalzare, you got it, right? Any other problem regarding to your question?

Comment: You're welcome @ujwalzare, if this helpful make this answer as accepted one which will help someone when they get this error again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class SampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta: 
    model = SampleModel
    fields = ['name']
```

Change the `from django.forms import forms` to `from django.forms import ModelForm` and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when attempting to execute the "makemigrations" command.

[image]

Upon reviewing the forms.py module, it has been identified that the letter 'f' should be capitalized in ModelForm.

[image]

Upon making the adjustments, the "makemigrations" command proceeded without any disruptions.